# Accessing application in browser over SSH proxy on localhost.

Tags: linux, macos, networking, ssh, proxy

I have SSH access to a web server that is hosting an application on port 8080.  I have a SSH session setup and a proxy configured on Chrome to redirect requests to SSH tunnel. I basically configured it using these instructions: http://drewsymo.com/2013/11/ssh-tunnel-in-30-seconds-mac-osx-linux/

I can confirm using Whats My IP that my IP is that of the SSH session and that is working correctly.

But I cannot figure out how to access the local application on the web server that I am SSHed into.  When I try localhost:8080 the SSH session gives me an error "channel X: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

You can just create a port-specific tunnel:

```
ssh -L18080:localhost:8080 username@theothermachine
```

and then go to `localhost:18080` on your local machine. The tunnel will forward your request to port 8080 of the localhost on the other end (and of course, localhost on the other end is the other machine itself). If that doesn't work for some reason, then replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 in the ssh command.